# Unity save the position of the object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like in UNITY to save the last object position when the user drag an object... so when i start again the scene or the app my gameobject is set in the last user position saved in local.

I am wondering which is the best way to implement it? do you know any good plug-in ?
is there a particlar setting?
thanks in advance for the negative vote  :-)

Comment: To save a variable on a scene change, you could probably use a `GameObject` with a simple script that is [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) to ensure it stays even if you reload the scene. Just make sure with a `static` variable that you only have 1 instance if you reload the same scene.

Comment: @IndieGameDev `static` is not necessary with `DontDestroyOnLoad`

Comment: @MickyD You are right that it isn't strictly necessary, but if you use `DontDestroyOnLoad` on a gameObject that is in the scene you were and the scene you transition too. It might cause problems if both scripts then execute and attempt to do the same thing. One might place the gameObject at their previous positions while the other one resets them to another position. Therefore using static to save an instance of the script and check at Awake if there is already an instance in the scene and destroying the duplicate one will resolve potential bottlenecks with `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Comment: @IndieGameDev 1) `static` isn't necessary in this scenario 2) Unity scripts all run in the main Unity Thread so threading issues don't apply 3) `static` isn't a synchronisation object and so won't protect you from threading issues even if Unity were multi-threaded 4) if you use `static` _anywhere_ in Unity beware _[thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html)_.  Unity is a CLR Host and it can and will **remove the Primary App Domain** without warning.

Comment: @MickyD Sorry it seems I misunderstood I assumed they were referring to reloading only the scene, but if they reload the whole application that will of course not work. They probably will have to use PlayerPrefs for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {
    // setting saved position on start
    void Start() {
        // checking if we have saved position, setting transform to it
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("posX") && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("posY")
            && PlayerPrefs.HasKey("posZ")) {
            transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("posX"),
                                             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("posY"),
                                             PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("posZ"));
        }

    // saving position before gameObject will be destroyed
    void OnDestroy() {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("posX", transform.position.x);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("posY", transform.position.y);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("posZ", transform.position.z);
    }
}
```